# Alacritty: Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png

Tags: gnome, icons, gtk, gvim

When I try to run gvim from a shell in [Alacritty](https://alacritty.org), I get the following error:

```
(gvim:9528): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:34:43.359: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
Vim: Finished.
E852: The child process failed to start the GUI
```

Launching gvim from the gnome desktop seems to work fine, however.  The specific icon file mentioned is accessible and does not appear to be corrupt.  I have seen many suggestions to run `update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` and also `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache`, but these do not fix the problem in my case.

Can anyone suggest anything else I can try to get this working from the command line?

Comment: Well, you could try with the command from the launcher / the file gvim.desktop : `gvim -f %F` . ...... Or if possible change icon in the file gvim.desktop to `Icon=gvim`

Comment: This only appears to be happening in alacritty, which is a snap application.  Launching from the gnome terminal is working normally.  So, I'm now assuming that this is likely a snap packaging issue.

Comment: Could you please file a bug or comment on existing ones [on GitHub](https://github.com/tunix/alacritty-snap/issues/19)? Please consider adding as much information as you can while you do. Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem, using alacrity to render preview [manin](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim) videos. Could you find a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In alacritty, two environment variables are set that mess with gvim, so to fix, add to your `.bashrc`:

```
unset GDK_PIXBUF_MODULEDIR
unset GDK_PIXBUF_MODULE_FILE
```

Comment: Nice!  This does indeed stop the error.  I don't understand enough to know why these are set and what I may be breaking by disabling these, but this is definitely helpful.  Thanks!